# Centralized computer with control possibilities from several locations within same network

Tags: networking, display, ethernet, desktop-computer, remote-control

In my new home I would like to make a different set up for my computer. I want to place my computer in a certain location in my house, like a closet or something. And then be able to access that computer on multiple locations in my house.

Preferably having only a computer monitor, mouse and keyboard connected to a device which communicates over Ethernet with my computer. If there is some sort device like this, I only have to buy 1  computer and just buy some monitors and connect them to my computer over Ethernet.

Like having 1 computer with a monitor, mouse and keyboard connected via very long wires so that you can use them in another room of your house.

Does anyone have experience with this, or knows devices which let you control your computer over Ethernet? If this does exists, would it be fast enough to, for example, play a game via the connection between the computer monitor and computer?

This is what I mean: http://www.jaycar.com.au/productView.asp?ID=XC4976

Comment: There are hundreds of remote desktop solutions.  Which solutions have you tried?

Comment: There's plenty of screen sharing and remote control tools that can kinda do that, but you generally wouldn't be able to play games through them. Then there are others dedicated to playing games. Even then, generally the clients aren't particularly cheap, so you might be better off with a laptop than permanent clients.

Comment: But I want to control that computer without any other computers involved. I know plenty of screen sharing programs from which you can control a computer USING an other computer. But I want to control my computer without an other computer in the middle. Like having a monitor, mouse and keyboard with extreme long wires so they can be used in another chamber of your house.

Comment: Please do not put tags in the title. This is not a forum, so "Answered" or "Solved" is not necessary in the title. The site automatically indicates answered questions when you accept an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reverse KVM setup could do this.

> A reverse KVM switch allows the connection of multiple KVM consoles (a
> keyboard, Video display and Mouse) to a single computer. Some reverse
> KVM switches also feature long distance extension of consoles to the
> target computer.

([source](http://www.adder.com/products/categories/reverse-kvm-switches))

[image]

There are numerious companies who make these. Do a Google search for Reverse KVM.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look in to thin clients such as Wyse terminals.  http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/cloud-client-computing  These terminals are generally designed for connecting to servers, however you may be able to use them to connect to your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Get fiber optic usb-c cables. They are available up to 100 feet, maybe more.

Run one cable from the main computer to each of your remote locations.

Connect to usb-c hubs at each remote location and plug in all of your devices.

You can even daisy chain them if the equipment is good quality.  For example, you  connect your computer to a 3-way USB-C splitter. Then you run your fiber optic USB-C cables from that splitter to each remote USB-C hub.

Fiber optic cables are not cheap, but they will give you the best outcome for long cable runs.

A reverse KVM seems like a nightmare if you want multiple remote locations.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).